# Are book-based answers saying "this didn't happen in the book" valid?

Tags: discussion

Are answers of the form "*This didn't actually happen in the book* (that movie is an adaptation of)" to a question "*Why did X happen in the movie*" acceptable?

Especially in cases where there seems to be no good movie-based answers?

Case in point: " [How did Crabbe and Goyle get into the advanced N.E.W.T. class?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13025/how-did-crabbe-and-goyle-get-into-the-advanced-n-e-w-t-class) "

The answer is: There's no explanation in the movie, and the book doesn't have them in the class so there's no canon reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Validity in this case is at the discretion of the asker I would argue.

If the flat fact is that "It didn't occur in the book, this is an oversight".  While that may be *factually correct* in terms of the universe (books/movie/games/etc), doesn't mean this is the answer the person is seeking.

If what the asker desires is "In the movie universe, why did **X** happen" then those answering are being explicitly asked to remain in the terms of the movie.

TLDR: it varies for each case.